XML a JSON devuelve sin informacion. PHP - Symfony
Tengo que pasar a JSON un XML que tiene la siguiente estructura:
<cfdi:A>
  <cfdi:B value="1" value2="2" />
  <cfdi:C value="1" value2="2" />
  <cfdi:d>
   <tfd:A value="1" />
  </cfdi:d>
</cfdi:A>

Cuando recibo el XML, tengo toda la informacion completa:
  $xmlContent = file_get_contents($xmlFilePath);       

  dd($xmlContent);

Pero cuando quiero hacer la conversion, no me aparece ningun valor. Y no encuentro como poder acceder a ellos.
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlContent, "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOCDATA, 'cfdi', true);
    dd($xml);


El XML está incompleto, no contiene la definición para los NS, por lo que tu código deberías estar lanzando advertencias al respecto.
Al margen de eso, si queres obtener un JSON del mismo, podes hacer:
$json = json_encode(simplexml_load_string($xmlContent));
dd($json);

Resultado:
'{"cfdi:B":{"@attributes":{"value":"1","value2":"2"}},"cfdi:C":{"@attributes":{"value":"1","value2":"2"}},"cfdi:d":{"tfd:A":{"@attributes":{"value":"1"}}}}'

Otra cosa que podes hacer es quitar los NS para así evitar las advertencias y obtener un JSON "más limpio", ejemplo:
$xmlContent = str_replace(['cfdi:', 'tfd:'], '', $xmlContent);
$json = json_encode(simplexml_load_string($xmlContent));
dd($json);

Resultado:
'{"B":{"@attributes":{"value":"1","value2":"2"}},"C":{"@attributes":{"value":"1","value2":"2"}},"d":{"A":{"@attributes":{"value":"1"}}}}'

Finalmente, si queres poder manipular los datos, podes convertilo a un array
$xmlContent = str_replace(['cfdi:', 'tfd:'], '', $xmlContent);
$array = json_decode(json_encode(simplexml_load_string($xmlContent)), true);
dd($array);

Resultado:
array ( 'B' => array ( '@attributes' => array ( 'value' => '1', 'value2' => '2', ), ), 'C' => array ( '@attributes' => array ( 'value' => '1', 'value2' => '2', ), ), 'd' => array ( 'A' => array ( '@attributes' => array ( 'value' => '1', ), ), ), )

Demo
